# How can I shape a subview to it's superview in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiprogressview

I am trying to add a `UIProgressView` along the top of a `UIView`. There is a border and rounded corners on the `UIView`. Currently it looks likes this:

[image: My UIProgressBar and UIView]

How can I get the `UIProgressBar` corners to follow those of the `UIView`?

The `UIProgressView` is a subview of the `UIView`. I have tried setting `clipsToBounds = true` but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

And code will look like:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    mainV.layer.masksToBounds = true
    mainV.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    mainV.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    mainV.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}
```

And result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make progressView rounded by:

```
self.progressView.layer.cornerRadius = //some int
```

But `clipsToBounds` property forces view to not to draw anything outside of the view's bounds.

Check your viewController hierarchy and make sure your progressView is subView of your view not the main view of viewController.